# How to read PostGIS point in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, postgis

I am currently getting PostGIS points at client side using JavaScript, is there a way to convert those points into ordinary x, y coordinates using JavaScript?

Here is how I get the points currently:

```
0101000020E6100000DE02098A1FF33F40BADA8AFD65F74140
```

Comment: this answer describes how to deal with the WKB format - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60050/wkb-to-wkt-javascript-function - although it would be probably better to adjust the SQL query to get the coordinates directly...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your actual query, but if you wrap the geometry referenced in your `SELECT` statement with [`ST_AsText()`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html) then it will return the geometry in a human readable format called [Well Known Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). 
e.g.

```
SELECT my_id, ST_AsText(my_geom) FROM my_table;
-- returns POINT(31.9497 35.9328) using the geometry from your question.
```

This is then fairly ordinary parsing exercise. Or, if you just want the raw lon / lat (or easting / northing), then structure your query like this:

```
SELECT ST_X(my_geom), ST_Y(my_geom) FROM my_table;
-- returns: 31.9497, 35.9328 using the geometry from your question
```

Note that you can also transform the geometry, if necessary, to the coordinate system that you need to use. For example, if the geometry is stored in the database in conventional lon/lat format ([EPSG code 4326](https://epsg.io/4326)) and you need to retrieve it in the Pseudo Mercator Projection ordinarily used in online maps ([EPSG code 3857](https://epsg.io/3857)), then you need to do this:

```
-- note the explicit ::geometry cast
SELECT my_id, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(my_geom::geometry, 3857)) FROM my_table;
```

For fun, you can try this in a PostGIS enabled Postgres SQL query window (using the geometry from your question):

Return as WKT:

```
SELECT  ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000DE02098A1FF33F40BADA8AFD65F74140');
-- returns: POINT(31.9497 35.9328)
```

Return as Pseudo Mercator:

```
SELECT  ST_AsText(ST_Transform('0101000020E6100000DE02098A1FF33F40BADA8AFD65F74140'::geometry, 3857))
-- returns: POINT(3556624.33499785 4291378.69099916)
```

Return as X, Y:

```
SELECT  ST_X('0101000020E6100000DE02098A1FF33F40BADA8AFD65F74140'),
    ST_Y('0101000020E6100000DE02098A1FF33F40BADA8AFD65F74140');
-- returns: 31.9497, 35.9328
```